# What is the role of get() and how to adjust frame rate?

Tags: python, opencv

At the following code I split video into frames. I got one image per second but I don't understand how it works exactly and what is going on while loop and what is the function of get(). I would be appreciated if somebody can explain.

```py
import cv2
import math

videoFile = "test3.avi"
imagesFolder = "D:\Video Frames"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
frameRate = cap.get(5) # frame rate
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(1) # current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename = imagesFolder + "/image_" +  str(int(frameId)) + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
print("Done!")
```

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939

Comment: Since you're reading a file, then it's futile trying to try to change the frame rate by setting `VideoCapture` properties -- the frames will always be decoded as fast as possible. It's up to you do display them at an appropriate rate (and you're not even displaying them, so I'm not sure what would be the point other that making your program just waste time).

Answer (score 2):

get is a method available to the VideoCapture class. From the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94), you can check the parameters. Each of the MACRO is a property of video with a corresponding integer value. For example,

cap.get(0) means CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, which in turn gives Current position of the video file in milliseconds or video capture timestamp.

cap.get(1) means CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES - 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.

Similarly, cap.get(5) means CAP_PROP_FPS - Frame rate of the video.

However, I think this is a bad practise to write code like this and one should use

cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS instead of cap.get(5) and so on.